# Open search result in multiple chrome tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, tabs

I am creating a search utility that will search various resources. I need to implement the search in a way where the results for each resource opens in a new tab. The code below works in firefox and IE, but in chrome only the first tab opens, and not the second one.

```
aForm.target="_blank";
aForm.submit();
```

I call this for each resource that I am searching (I manipulate some for variables before each submit). As I said this works in firefox and IE, but not in Chrome? Any suggestions? chrome extensions has a chrome.tabs.create() method, but for that I need to create an extension for chrome, which all users will have to install, and I would really like to avoid having to install an extension.

Also, window.open(...) for chrome opens new windows instead of tabs.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you increment the name to change the target? So aForm="newWindow"+n, each iteration would open a new tab/window at newWindow1, newWindow2, etc.

Comment: I have tried changing the target name for each tab, but that didn't help.

Comment: Well, the calls are definitely all going to the same window. I noticed that it only happens if the submit()s are running on the same thread - if you put it in a setTimeout(..., 100), they open separately, but every one after the first is in a new window, so it's still no good. I'm stumped, wish I had more to tell you.